# linear transformation properties

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear function $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $T(x)=Px$, where $P^T = P^{-1}$.

Prove that for any two vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $|T(x)|=|x|$ and $T(x).T(y)=x.y$. Also prove that T is continuous.

Anyone can give me hints on how to approach this question?

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

1. $|z| = \sqrt{z^T z} \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
2. $x.y = x^T y \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Plug these in, expand $T$ in terms of $P$ and do arithmetic.

**EDIT** Let's try to make a couple more steps.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
$$
|T(x)| = \sqrt{T(x).T(x)} = \sqrt{T(x)^T T(x)} = \sqrt{(Px)^T (Px)} = \sqrt{x^T x} = |x|,
$$
as desired.

Can you explain why $(Px)^T (Px) = x^T x$?

Comment: sorry but i still dont quite understand what you mean. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @user108297 see the edit with a further hint

Comment: because (P^T)(P)=I??

Comment: I guess I understand the steps now!
But where do the two hints come from? Are they just definition?

Comment: @user108297 yes - just compute both sides term by term. I forgot one thing - $|z| = \sqrt{z^T z}$. Made the changes...

Comment: One last question..how to prove T is continuous then?

Comment: @user108297 Use the standard $\delta-\epsilon$ definition of continuity from here, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_definition_.28epsilon-delta.29_of_continuous_functions and plug in the above definition of $|T(\vec{x})| = |\vec{x}|$.